# NodeJS Bcrypt hashing & comparing takes 2-3 seconds on average. How to optimize it

Tags: javascript, node.js, bcrypt

NodeJS Bcrypt hashing & comparing takes 2-3 seconds on average. How to optimize it.
Is there any alternative solution for password hashing with millisecond-level performance?

Please suggest modifications required in the code below:

```
bcrypt.hash(password, 15).then(hashedPassword => {  } 

bcrypt.compare(password, savedUser.password).then(doMatch => {   }
```

Comment: it's part of the point for password hashing to take time. Bcrypt taking multiple turns is on purpose. And this takes time.

Comment: 2-3 seconds is usually too long – you should aim for about 0.1 seconds. Are you using a pure-JavaScript implementation? How many rounds?

Comment: You can make bcrypt faster by tuning the work factor, but a rule of thumb would be on the order of 0.1s, not 0.001s (see e.g. https://security.stackexchange.com/a/3993/72084).

Comment: I have added my code in the question. Could you please check and suggest modifications required

Comment: 15 is too high. Use 12 or 13.